# Modified variable not passed in wordpress filter hook

Tags: wordpress, hook

I am using a (free) plugin to create filters to view posts on frontend, this plugin comes with various hooks, including one to modify the output after filtering. There I would like to add post date and taxonomies.

This is my function (as suggested in the docs of the plugin, called in the header, 95195 is the right id):

```
function filter_callback( $html, $entry ) {
    $html .= 'test'; // to check if it does anthing, which it doesn't
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'wfa_directory_entry_html_95195', 'filter_callback', 10, 2 );
```

This filter is applied in this section of the plugin code:

```
$full_html = '';
        if ( $entries->have_posts() ) :
            while ( $entries->have_posts() ) : $entries->the_post();
                $entry = $entries->post;
                ob_start();
                include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '../templates/tp-directory-result-item.php';
                $html = ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();
                $full_html .= apply_filters( 'wfa_directory_entry_html_' . $directory_id, $html, $entry );
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        endif;
```

I tried doing anything to the $html in the function - nothing changes. When I append stuff directly to $full_html it works, but this is not a solution. I suspect maybe the filter is applied before it is added - but I don't know how to check for that, nor how to change it.

I would appreaciate suggestions what to try next :)